# How to perform certain actions of a button (OK / SUBMIT) automatically without pressing the regarding buttons in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code for the ok button of a dialog in the javascript file:

```
onOk: function() {

                  var selection = this._.editor.getSelection(),
                  bookmarks = selection.createBookmarks();

                  var cells = this.cells;

                  for ( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
                        this.commitContent( cells[ i ] );

                  this._.editor.forceNextSelectionCheck();
                  selection.selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
                  this._.editor.selectionChange();
},
```

So, in the dialog when I press ok certain actions have been performed [image]

And here I need to press the ok button for my text area:

```
commit: function( element ) {

                              var value=20;

                              unit = this.getDialog().getValueOf( 'info', 'widthType' ) || getCellWidthType( element );

                              element.setStyle( 'width', value + unit );
},
```

Now, I want the action of the ok button to be performed without pressing the ok button.

So, used the function as self invoking function and execute it inside the commit like that:

```
commit: function( element ) {                       

             var value=20;
             unit = this.getDialog().getValueOf( 'info', 'widthType' ) || getCellWidthType( element );

            (function() {

                var selection = this._.editor.getSelection(),
                bookmarks = selection.createBookmarks();

                var cells = this.cells;

                for ( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
                             this.commitContent( cells[ i ] );

                this._.editor.forceNextSelectionCheck();
                selection.selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
                this._.editor.selectionChange();

            }) ();

                element.setStyle( 'width', value + unit );                      
},
```

But it is not working.

Is there anyway that the code inside `onOK` will be executed automatically every time ?

Answer (score 2):

you can simulate a click event on the desired button. By doing so, all the event listener for the click event will be called. So if `onOK` is attached to the click event of the button, simulating a click on that button will call it automatically. Here is how to simulate a click event on an element:

```
// select the element
var element = document.getElementById("someId");
// simulate the click event on that element
element.click();
```

Here is an example, where you can simulate a click event on a button, thus, calling it's click event listener automatically (without actually clicking the button):

```js
var  onOK =  function() {
   alert("ok  clicked");
}
  
var element = document.getElementById("okbutton");
element.click();
```

```html
<div >
  <button onclick ="onOK()" id="okbutton">click here </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the new function declaration into function like this

```
commit: function( element ) {                       
    var value=20;
    unit = this.getDialog().getValueOf( 'info', 'widthType' ) || getCellWidthType( element );

    // OK button Code here
    var selection = this._.editor.getSelection(),
    bookmarks = selection.createBookmarks();

    var cells = this.cells;
    for ( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
        this.commitContent( cells[ i ] );

    this._.editor.forceNextSelectionCheck();
    selection.selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
    this._.editor.selectionChange();
    //OK button code complete

    element.setStyle( 'width', value + unit );                      
}
```

But, still `this` keyword will consider all things of `commit` button now, so for the ok button you need it to specify it with id or class like

```
var thisEle = $("#okButtonIdHere");
var selection = thisEle._.editor.getSelection(),
bookmarks = selection.createBookmarks();

var cells = thisEle.cells;
for ( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
    thisEle.commitContent( cells[ i ] );

thisEle._.editor.forceNextSelectionCheck();
selection.selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
thisEle._.editor.selectionChange();
```

**Updated Answer Here**

Your this code is working fine

```
commit: function( element ) {

  var value=20;

  unit = this.getDialog().getValueOf( 'info', 'widthType' ) || getCellWidthType( element );

  element.setStyle( 'width', value + unit );
},
```

Now you want to perform OK button click from this `commit` function. So as per the answer of Dinesh Shah you can set onclick function on id of that button like below

**Whole Code**

```
commit: function( element ) {

  var value=20;

  unit = this.getDialog().getValueOf( 'info', 'widthType' ) || getCellWidthType( element );

  element.setStyle( 'width', value + unit );

  $("#okbuttonId").click();
},

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#okbuttonId").click(function(){
        var selection = this._.editor.getSelection(),
        bookmarks = selection.createBookmarks();

        var cells = this.cells;

        for ( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ ){
            this.commitContent( cells[ i ] );
        }
        this._.editor.forceNextSelectionCheck();
        selection.selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
        this._.editor.selectionChange();
    });
});
```

This way you can call the similar functionality of OK button which working for you. Let me know if this is working or not.

Comment: ,,, No. in that way, it doesn't work. Do you have any other solution left ?  I have also tried with on change method of jquery .. but it also fails..

Comment: Please check my updated answer, if you are using jquery then this will work for you.